# Removing inner padding from Google linechart visualization

Tags: google-visualization

Does anyone know of a way to remove the default padding that appears either side of the inner chart area, as highlighted in light blue in this [screengrab](http://filesource10.net/lineChart.jpg)

[image]

Here is the code I'm current using to generate the chart...

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      [<?php echo $colTitles; ?>], 
      <?php echo $values; ?>
    ]);

    var options = {
        width: 785, height: 440,
        chartArea: {top:20,left:20,right:0,bottom:0,width:"70%",height:"80%"},
        legend: {position: 'right', textStyle: {fontSize: 10}, alignment: 'start'},
        hAxis: {
            direction:-1,
            slantedText:true,
            slantedTextAngle:90 // here you can even use 180
        },
        vAxis: {maxValue:40, minValue:0, format:'#',gridlines:{count:10}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Comment: +1 for asking a good formatted question at the very first time.

Answer (score 0):

Antonio,

I've never seen a request like that, and looking at the API there is not a `vAxis` option for starting the lines at some point (pixel) specified.

Anyway, I [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BrOSs/aRuzF/) a working-around solution using CSS style options.

Basically, I just cropped the right padding part of the chart, and placed the vAxis titles inside for keeping the titles and draw on (*aprovechar el espacio*) that padding blank space.

*Saludos!*

Comment: I also struggled to find anything in the API to specific the starting/end points of the lines. I've added in the `textPosition:'in'` to the vAvis and set the left padding of the chartarea to 0 and its certainly helped, but the spacing either side of the chart still seems excessive... [link](http://www.bicom.org.uk/analysis/spotlight/elections-2012/?test#election-polls)

Comment: Well, I'm just thinking about changing the chart type for someone more customizable.